# Laravel: display data in view without Eloquent

Tags: laravel, view, model, load, eloquent

Let's say I need to display a list of articles in a view. So I run a complex query to get all needed data and I get a resulting table, for example, like this:

| id | article_name | article_body | article_tag_id | ... (many more columns)

There is also a model defined: Article.php.

Question: what is the proper way to prepare data for view in Laravel? I'd also like to add that I'm looking for a way to do this without using Eloquent. Sure I could just do $articles = `Article::all();` but what if I'm dealing with very complex queries and I need to load objects manually by controlling the loading logic.

In the case above, what I would like to do is to create a model and pass each row to a method load() like this:

```
$model = new Article();
$model.load(row);
array_push($dataForView, $model);
```

and finally send data to view

```
return view('articles')->with('articles', $dataForView);
```

Is this something I should do in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you want to be avoiding Eloquent all together.  But you can abstract your complex query to a method on your model:

```
// article.php

public function my_complex_query()
{

    // code here. Eloquent, or Query Builder or 
    // Raw SQL

    return $result;

}
```

Then call that from your Controller:

```
return view('the-view')
    ->withArticles(Article::my_complex_query());

// or you can inject your model into your controller and call $this->article->my_complex_query()
```

And then loop through the data in your view. This is the beauty of eloquent because it maps your database results to an object.

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
{{ $article->name }}
// ...
@endforeach
```